# How to find Minecraft on a Mac

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, macos

My brother put Minecraft on my mac so that he could play it. Unfortunately, he hid it from me and I have been looking everywhere for it. He probably changed the name and picture though. Where could I find it?

Comment: I would recommend typing "minecraft.exe" (no quotes) into the computer's search bar.

Comment: @NickB. "Mac" "changed the name"

Comment: @Ealhad, I'm not very familiar with Apple's computers, but I assumed they have a search function of some sort. And I doubt the OP's brother actually changed the name of the executable file.

Comment: @NickB.: Macs don't use `.exe` files in the first place.

Comment: @NickB. I'm not really familiar with it either, but I know they don't usually use `.exe` specific to windows (they can, though, as all UNIX system, with wine). And if I were the brother, I would totally have changed the name :p

Comment: @Ealhad: Sorry, I'm so used to Windows that I'm forgetting that it's different from the other operating system. I'll change my original comment to `.app`

Comment: You could always change the password on your Mac and hold it hostage until your brother shows you where he put the files.

Comment: cmd + space to bring up spotlight, then search for minecraft

Answer (score 2):

You actually don't need to find it (and nobody except your brother could help you anyway, it's your computer). You can just go to `~/Library/Application Support/minecraft`, and launch the game from there.

Comment: Granted, I am not on a mac, but I have absolutely nothing in `.minecraft` that I can actually use to launch the game. The `.jar` files do nothing without the correct command line arguments and the `launcher.jar` is located elsewhere for me.

Comment: _I'd recommend beating your brother till he tells you._

What do you mean, you are not on a mac ?

Comment: I meant that I am not 100% sure my comment applies on a mac as well. But on the windows machine I'm sitting right now, nothing in `.minecraft` launches the game.

Comment: Well, for me `java -jar launcher.jar` works just fine. Sorry, I can't verify that on Windows nor on OS X, I have nothing of the sort near me :/